# Submit Form into specific window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML form in a popup window's iframe and would like to submit it into the popup's opening window (window.parent.opener). The form does not exist in the opening window, but only in the popup's iframe. What's the easiest way to do this?

I figure form targets don't help, as they only allow to specify _parent, and the opening window does not have an iframename. Dynamically re-creating the iframe's form in the opening window could be an option, as long as it does not become visible. Is there a library to dynamically create a form given serialized form data?

(jQuery solutions preferred)

Comment: Did you consider making an ajax request to the parent page to get the form values?

Comment: The popup (or, rather, the iframe in the popup) should make the opening window submit a POST request and display the result. Ajax would help with submitting the data, but would not change the content of the opening window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically re-creating the form in the other window turned out to be not as bad as I thought. This snippet should do it:

```
var originalForm = $('#myForm');
var values = originalForm.serializeArray();
var newForm = $('<form>').attr({method: 'post', action: originalForm.prop('action')});
$.each(values, function(i, val) {
    newForm.append($('<input>').attr({type: 'hidden'}).attr(val));
});
$('body', window.parent.opener.document).append(newForm);
newForm.submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you serialize all the data from the form and pass it to the parent via `window.parent.opener` ?

Or use the URL with something like `window.parent.opener.location = "http://something.com?var1=test&var2=test"`.

**For POST, try dinamically setting the target:**

`document.whateverForm.target = window.parent.opener.window.name;`

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer not to add the form (or any JavaScript that has knowledge about it) in the parent page.
Using window.location would result in a HTTP GET, but this should definitely be done by a HTTP POST.

Comment: Check the answer for the edit. It should work to set the target programatically.

Comment: That's a pretty cool idea :) Unfortunately I doubt that it will work, at least on all browsers. In my Chrome, the name is "".